# Is async always asynchronous in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task

I am doing R&D on `async` and `await` for my project. What I have learned is that when `async` method is called, it frees the thread and let the thread to be used by others. We can set callback for await-able method using `await` keyword and that method returns value when the result is ready. If that happens:

1. We should be able to access the `UI` briefly between operations.
2. Execution time should be faster than the usual synchronous method call.

In my case, I have no question about `point 1`, But for `point 2`, it's execution time seems same as the synchronous method call. For example see `Sample Code 1` and `Sample Output 1`

**Sample Code 1:**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before Async Call");
            AsyncMethod();
            Console.WriteLine("After Async Call");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public async static void AsyncMethod()
        {
            var firstValue = FirstAsyncMethod("FirstAsyncMethod has been called");
            Console.WriteLine("Middle of FirstAsyncMethod and SecondAsyncMethod");
            var secondValue = SecondAsyncMethod("SecondAsyncMethod has been called");
            Console.WriteLine(await firstValue);
            Console.WriteLine(await secondValue);
        }

        public static async Task<string> FirstAsyncMethod(string value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
            {
                i = i + 1 - 1;
            }
            return "Success: "+value;
        }
        public static async Task<string> SecondAsyncMethod(string value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
            {
                i = i + 1 - 1;
            }
            return "Success: " + value;
        }
    }
```

**Sample Output 1:**

```
Before Async Call
Middle of FirstAsyncMethod and SecondAsyncMethod
Success: FirstAsyncMethod has been called
Success: SecondAsyncMethod has been called
After Async Call
```

But if I call the `async` method with `Task.Run(()=> )` (For example `Sample Code 2` and `Sample Output 2`), it reduces the execution time compared to first example (`Sample Code 1`).

**Sample Code 2:**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before Async Call");
            AsyncMethod();
            Console.WriteLine("After Async Call");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public async static void AsyncMethod()
        {
            var firstValue =Task.Run(()=> FirstAsyncMethod("FirstAsyncMethod has been called"));
            Console.WriteLine("Middle of FirstAsyncMethod and SecondAsyncMethod");
            var secondValue = Task.Run(() => SecondAsyncMethod("SecondAsyncMethod has been called"));
            Console.WriteLine(await firstValue);
            Console.WriteLine(await secondValue);
        }

        public static async Task<string> FirstAsyncMethod(string value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
            {
                i = i + 1 - 1;
            }
            return "Success: "+value;
        }
        public static async Task<string> SecondAsyncMethod(string value)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
            {
                i = i + 1 - 1;
            }
            return "Success: " + value;
        }
    }
```

**Sample Output 2:**

```
Before Async Call
Middle of FirstAsyncMethod and SecondAsyncMethod
After Async Call
Success: FirstAsyncMethod has been called
Success: SecondAsyncMethod has been called
```

My question is, why the first example (`Sample Code 1`) taking time like synchronous method call?

Comment: I'd always recommend [Asynchronous Programming in C# 5.0 part two: Whence await?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await/) by Eric Lippert to get rid of the worst misunderstandings. "**The whole point of async methods it that you stay on the current thread as much as possible**"

Comment: It's incredible how in 2016 there's still people asking the same question all over again. I would say that this has been answered many times and even MSDN has good articles explaining how async-await works.

Comment: Adding async to completely synchronous code does not make it asynchronous...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'm sure this question has been asked before (most questions have). However that question you pointed to as a duplicate asks for a technical explanation as to *How can I have an operation executed in parallel on the same thread?*, while this questions asks *Why is an async method taking time like a synchronous method would?*. I would say those are two different questions.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis BTW, the other Q&A has enough details to let the OP solve the question him/herself. This is my point.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I've voted to re-open. The duplicate question does not have an answer that explains when an async method is executed async or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async is not always asynchronous. Visual Studio should display a warning that the first method is not asynchronous because there is nothing to await.

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls,
>   or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread

Note that the use of async void is considered a bad practice these days. You should always use async Taks for the return type of async methods.

[See this article for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)